# Print text using for loop inside box in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the shiny dashboard below and I want to print inside the box `"Red1"` to `"Red21"` one below the other using a `for()` loop like in the screenshot. The `box()` should be created with `renderUI()`

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(minified = TRUE, collapsed = TRUE),
    body = dashboardBody(
      uiOutput("box1")
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$box1<-renderUI({

        box(
          for(i in 1:21){
            "Red"[i]
            br()
          },
          height = 300,width = 5
        )
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box()` can take a list as first argument, so your code can be rewritten like this:

```
...
box({
  text <- list()
  for(i in 1:21){
    text <- append(text, list(paste("Red", i), br()))
  }
  text
})
...
```

Doing this with an anonymous function (which this is) isn't that good for readability (at least for me) so I would suggest you build that list beforehand.